# Kit Assembly - Custom Date Field

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We need to add a custom field to store the Kit Assembly Start Date, but are unable to complete this task due to error "Table does not exist in database: INKitRegister"

If we needed a Date field instead of a text field and decorated our custom field with the following attributes + added PXDateTimeEdit on the Kit Assembly screen:

[image]

Now we receive a not very clear error message while entering some value in custom PXDateTimeEdit:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INKitRegister DAC is decorated with PXProjectionAttribute and works with the INRegister database table - therefore you received the error message reported:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(KitAssemblyEntry))]
[PXCacheName(Messages.INKit)]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<INRegister, InnerJoin<INTran,
    On<INRegister.kitLineNbr, Equal<INTran.lineNbr>,
        And<INRegister.docType, Equal<INTran.docType>,
        And<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<INTran.refNbr>>>>>>), Persistent = true)]
[Serializable]
public partial class INKitRegister : IBqlTable, ILSPrimary
{
    ...
}
```

As of right now Customization Manager does not support projection DACs and we'll have to right some code to add custom field on the Kit Assembly screen:

1.In Customization Manager add new field for the IN.INRegister DAC following the screenshot below:
[image]

2. In Customization Manager add new Code file selecting DAC Extension as File Type and INKitRegister as Base DAC following the screenshot below:
   [image]
3. Declare custom UsrTest field within the generated INKitRegister DAC extension:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Text;
   using PX.Data;
   using PX.Objects.CS;
   using PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease;
   using PX.Objects.GL;
   using PX.Objects.CM;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using PX.Objects;
   using PX.Objects.IN;

   namespace PX.Objects.IN
   {
     public class INKitRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INKitRegister>
     {
       #region UsrTest
       public abstract class usrTest: PX.Data.IBqlField
       {
       }
       protected String _BatchNbr;
       [PXDBString(50, BqlField = typeof(INRegisterExt.usrTest))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test")]
       public virtual string UsrTest { get; set; }
       #endregion
     }
   }
   ```

Note: to obtain BqlField name required for the DB[Type]Attribute, one should open INRegister custom field declaration in the Data Class Editor:
[image]

4. Publish current project
5. Open Layout Editor for the Kit Assembly screen to add input control for the custom field declared within the INKitRegister DAC extension:
   [image]
6. Publish current project and navigate to the Kit Assembly screen to make sure if customization was successfully applied:
   [image]

To resolve "Unable to cast object of type A to type B" error, you should verify 2 things:

1. if field attributes match in extensions of the INRegister and the INKitRegister DACs
2. you declared field of the right type

[image]

In this specific case, the issue was resolved by changing type of the UsrKAStartDate to DateTime? (Nullable):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using System.Diagnostics;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    public class INKitRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INKitRegister>
    {
        #region UsrKAStartDate
        [PXDBDate]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Date")]
        public virtual DateTime? UsrKAStartDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrKAStartDate : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @RuslanDev, Instead of using INRegister table, I have created a extension table with few columns with default system column, when we select inventory then i am showing a checkbox checked and a value in a Textbox, but checkbox doesn't checked and textbox is also now showing value. I am assign all properties on FieldUpdated event of inventoty, what i am missing? I have added a tab and then formview, inside a FORMView i have added checkbox and Textbox but values are not showing. what am i missing?